# Too few arguments for a c# to vb.net conversion

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
Friend Shared Sub dumpRows(rowList As System.Collections.Generic.List, msg As [String])
            msg = If((msg Is Nothing), "***** ", "***** " & msg)
            Dim row As [Object] = Nothing
            info(vbLf & msg)
            info("** Begin Row Dump:")
            Dim iter As Iterator = rowList.iterator()
            While iter.hasNext()
                row = iter.[next]()
                info(row.ToString())
            End While
            info("** End Row Dump." & vbLf)
        End Sub
```

On the first line, I am getting the error: Too few arguments to system.collections.generic.list(of T)

Comment: I don't use VB.NET, but aren't you supposed to specify the type of the list?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be `System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Object)` where `Object` is the actual type contained in your list.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would write it:

```
Friend Shared Sub dumpRows(rowList As List(Of Object), msg As String)
    msg = "***** " & If(msg, String.Empty)
    info(vbLf & msg)
    info("** Begin Row Dump:")
    Dim iter As Iterator = rowList.iterator()
    While iter.hasNext()
        Dim row As Object = iter.[next]()
        info(row.ToString())
    End While
    info("** End Row Dump." & vbLf)
End Sub
```

As others have stated, you need to declare what type the `List` contains.

A few other notes:

1. I removed the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace from the front
   of the class name since I believe this namespace is imported by
   default.  You might have to add it back, but I doubt it.
2. I don't know why the conversion tool you used put square brackets around the class name `String`.  They aren't necessary.
3. Since you are basically just setting `msg` to have 5 asterisks in    front of whatever it was previously, you can use a coalesce instead 
   of a ternary conditional.  This makes the code a little cleaner IMO.
4. There is no reason to declare `row` in that large of a scope if it is only being used within the `While` loop.